# Calculate the height in pixels that corresponds to a value on the axis of D3 graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a D3 bar chart as follows:

[image]

I want to color the bars that pass the horizontal line the color green. I can do this as follows:

```
.attr("fill", function(d) { return (d.the_value > 0.65 ? "green" : "orange"); })
```

which works great. But the height of the horizontal bar itself is set using the height of the plot.

```
    svg.append("line")         
    .style("stroke", "black")  
    .attr("x1", 0)     
    .attr("y1", height/2)    
    .attr("x2", 600)
    .attr("y2", height/2);
```

I want to set the height of the horizontal bar by using the value 0.65. How can I get the height in pixels that corresponds to 0.65 on the axis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you have something in your code like

```
yScale = d3.scale()
  .domain(...)
  .range([0, 600])
```

and that you use it to size and position the bars.

With that scale you can get the y-coordinate you're after using `yScale(0.65)`. I.e.:

```
svg.append("line")         
.style("stroke", "black")  
.attr("x1", 0)     
.attr("y1", yScale(0.65))    
.attr("x2", 600)
.attr("y2", yScale(0.65));
```